# miserable failure vs complete failure

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What the difference between **"miserable failure"** and **"complete failure"**? Feel free to provide some examples, if it needs.

Is "miserable failure" something like "horrible failure"?

Comment: The full OED has the example usage *His success was after all a miserable failure* under definition **3a** *Of a thing: pitiable, deplorable* - where they say that sense now usually overlaps with **3b** *Pathetically unworthy, inadequate, or meagre; contemptible, despicable; paltry, mean.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I can't understand that answer. My question is about the certain phrase, not in general.

Comment: The OED gives a lot of "synonyms" for this sense of "miserable" - ***pitiable, deplorable, pathetic, unworthy, inadequate, meagre, contemptible, despicable, paltry, mean***. Even if you don't understand *all* of them, that list should give you a pretty good idea of the *general* sense intended.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I am afraid you don't understand my question. You wrote synonyms  that do not correspond to the question.

Comment: You're asking the difference between "miserable failure" and "complete failure", and I assume you don't have a problem with what "complete" means in this context. I've given you the full relevant definitions from the best dictionary in the world *by far, for **any** language* - and anyone can see it's *exactly* relevant to your question, because one of their actual cited usage examples is the very collocation ***miserable failure*** as in your question. But as they say - you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, There is no value to write the full relevant definitions if the question was about the difference between "miserable failure" and "complete failure". If you try to answer to the question, you have to carefully read it. Otherwise, it is a pointless work. But, if your goal is completed, it's a miserable failure. I think, I have understood that meaning thanks to Kate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling something a *miserable failure* is just a more emotive way of saying that it failed completely. It implies that the failure was so bad as to be ignominious.